# How to Reset clear the values in a Typescript class

Tags: angular, typescript, angular7, angular8

How do I reset the values in a class in Typescript and ensure all the values are cleared? Is there a typescript function to do this?

```
export class Product{
   productId: number; 
   productName: string;
   productDescription: string;
}
```

We have many classes with 50+ fields, looking for efficient way to conduct this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this:

**[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-b5y5om?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts)**

```
productDetails: Product = {
  productId: 1,
  productName: "Apple",
  productDescription: "Fruit"
};

reset() {
  this.productDetails = new Product();
}
```

Comment: thanks, I will try this, and no () after new Product? , like new Product(),  great, different than .net, appreciate it

Comment: @AdritaSharma i think you have to write the default constructor also. Otherwise it clear all the properties... After reset it will be {}

Comment: OP wants to reset all values I assume

Comment: @AdritaSharma after calling this he needs to construct his properties again

Answer (score 1):

YOu can create a function and set your all states to default value

```
export class Product{
  productId: number; 
  productName: string;
  productDescription: string;

  resetValues() {
    this.productId = 0; //default of number datatype is 0
    this.productName = null;
    this.productDescription = null;
  }
}
```