# how to define initial state for Angular service

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Don't know i have to ask or not but just came thought in mind so asking.
i have situation like some service or class variable value i have modified after doing some operation inside component but is there any way to get what was the service or class initial state before modified by this component.

MyService

```js
@Injectable()
export class MyService {
  public a = "";
  public b = false;
  public c = "";
  ...
}
```

MyComponent

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'mycomp',
  templateUrl: './mycomp.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./mycomp.component.styles.scss']
})

export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private myService: MyService) {

  }
  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.myService.a = "";
    this.myService.b = false;
    this.myService.c = "";
    ...
  }
}
```

because my service contains thousands of variables,and i want to reset all service variables modified by the component, on component destroy.

is it possible to reset initial stage for the Service class?

Thanks.

Comment: If I'm gettint it clear --> [How to Reset clear the values in a Typescript class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58947764/how-to-reset-clear-the-values-in-a-typescript-class)

Comment: Instead of reinitialize instance,looking for just before component got initialized what was the stage for the service class.

Comment: What @CarlosGamarra said.  The easiest way is to have your variables in their own class which you can re-instantiate and re-assign.

Comment: thank you..got it...+v

Comment: If you want to have a new service for each new component, try using [Angular directives instead](https://angular.io/guide/attribute-directives)